# How to get results into called js from service calls js in react native ?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im new to react native, and to make service calls Im creating a different file say 'NetworkCalls.js', the file is as follows :

```
var NetworkCalls = {

callUsingGETRequest: function(URL){
fetch(URL, {method: "GET"})
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
          return responseData.ip;
      })
      .done();
}
}
```

Now Im calling this function from index.ios.js file as

```
NetworkCalls.callUsingGETRequest(('http://ip.jsontest.com/'),(response) => {
  console.log(response);
})
}
```

importing is done , and even im receiving response, but the result never came back into this function block and it never gets printed.

This may be noob question, but where Im working wrong ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `Promise` from `callUsingGETRequest`

```
var NetworkCalls = {
  callUsingGETRequest: function (URL) {
    return fetch(URL, { method: "GET" })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => responseData.ip)
  }
}
```

and then use it, like this

```
NetworkCalls
  .callUsingGETRequest('http://ip.jsontest.com/')
  .then(ip => {
    console.log(ip);
  });
```

Comment: Also I would like to know if there is some good documentation about syntax like these to understand. @Alexander

Comment: @RSD there is doc on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise, and about fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Thanks :) @Alexander